# How to have Angular Components which refer to other?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

We have different modules in the Angular Application: Customer, Product, Sales, Inventory, Marketing, etc.

What's occurring- sometimes different customer, product forms, components, etc  can be required  in other components.

So Inventory may need customer,  Product requires marketing, etc

Our team is discussing two options ,

1) Either have all the modules reference to each other; team is reluctant to conduct since, it may become a network cobweb model and difficult to maintain.

2) Or place everything into Shared Module. However lot of these components are shared , so 60-70% may end up in this.

Curious if there is third option, not requiring every file to be relocated to Shared, and something easier to maintain.

Comment: How new is this team? Is this a team of professionals, or students? I would look into basic OOP principles. Also you need to be more clear, are we talking about modules or components?

Comment: hi @Josh components in different modules, can you give me a keyword or something I should research, many of the websites, are recommending just a shared module

Comment: @MattSmith74 If there will be tons of components to share try to split them to smaller shared modules and try to use them independent as much as you can.

Comment: hi @Mises would proxy or facade pattern work for modules, researching this

Comment: @MattSmith74 I'm not an expert that why im only write comment.

Comment: Instead of having components depending one another, have your data models depend on one another instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with Independent Modules of each component. Suppose if you need to use a component of customer form in multiple modules. Instead of adding all component in SharedModule, **Make that component an independent module** and import it in your required modules. By doing this your components would be more flexible, dynamic, smart and reuseable.

It also gives you the flexibility to only use desired component in your module. If you make one SharedModule and you only need customer form from that module. You have to import the whole module which might have bunch of other components which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

When the Application starts growing, splitting components in to business modules is the best practice. It is really easy to maintain.

**Shared Module Concept**:
The shared module concept could be introduced if the elements in UI / business model in UI(dialog box, tooltip etc.,) should be common across the application. You may want to have the similar UX across the App.

To refer components which are not part of current module, you can load the components using dynamic component loader concept. Please refer the angular documentation. You can write this dynamic loader generically, so that you can use across.
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

What are we trying to achieve here is to delegate the component reference in runtime by angular itself.

Comment: well this answer does not really address the issue, of number 2 (I already stated Shared Module) above, and the concern that everything may roll into shared module, etc,

Comment: well, i mean, Shared Module concept is introduced only if the elements in UI / business model needs to be same across the application which means that shared module for referring components should be the right choice.

use dynamic component loader for referring other components. take the instance of component you are trying to load from component factory and load it. The Components will stay as is now.

Comment: so basically most of our application will be in the shared module, hopefully angular created a better practice